# Print a file in Python on Windows without opening it

Tags: python, pdf, printing, cmd

Running the following line of python causes Adobe Acrobat to launch

```
win32api.ShellExecute(0, "print", "myC.pdf", None, ".", 0)
```

Adobe is my default PDF viewer. Why is Adobe opening? How can I prevent this from happening?

The script meant to run many times on a slow PC.

I do not understand how `print` works from `ShellExecute`. Typing `print myC.pdf` in the command prompt gives me the error "Unable to initialize device PRN". A little background would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**print**ing the file at the system level is a command to display the file.  Adobe's viewer is the application associated with this file.  What are you *expecting* to happen?  If you want to operate on the file with some other application, then you'll have to specify that through a more focused interface.

**print** is equivalent to the GUI sequence right-clink + Print.  The first thing that **print** does is to open the file; Windows doesn't have a default interface to print a file without opening it normally.

I found you a couple of references that know even more than I do:  :-)

- A related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16604844/shellexecute-print)
- The MS documentation on [ShellExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I expect the command to print the file myC.pdf to a label maker. The label does print due to this command. Is this command telling Adobe to print the file?

Comment: Ah ... so you get the desired effect; your only problem is that it also displays the file on the console?

Comment: @petEEy: exactly. As phyton has no knowledge of the file contents (and isn't able to handle it on it's own), it _needs_  the proper application to read (and print) it.